# How to pass string to javascript funciton which contains special characters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have this little php snippet:

```
       // $test='test';

       $test='just a test';
       echo "<a href=javascript:myfunction($number,$src_req,\"".$test."\")><img style='z-index:$z; src='images/$src'/></a>";
```

And i have this little ajax snippet...

```
function myfunction(param1,param2,param3)
{
  var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
    {
      HandleResponse2(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  var p1=param1;
  var p2=param2;
  var p3=param3;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", "config/ajax_pop.php", true); 
  xmlHttp.send(null);


  $( '#ResponseDiv2' ).dialog({     
        height: 140, 
        modal: true, 
        position: [490,140], 
        title:param3,

  }); 
  .....
```

I like to pass my $test php variable to my javascript function, but unfortunatelly if my $test variable contain **space** character then the JS script doesnt work. If my $test variable contain only one word, then work well.

In the browser when i check the link i see:

a, if $test variable contain only one word, then: javascript:myfunction(1,1,"test")

b, if $test variable contain more then one words then: javascript:myfunction(1,1,"just

Thank you for the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap the `href` itself with double quotes then the value with single quotes:

```
href=\"javascript:myfunction($number, $src_req, '".$test."')\"
```

Comment: after check the link a see: javascript:myfunction(1,1,\'just a test\'), but the JS still dont work.

Comment: @hol no that's not good because the final HTML will be: `<a href=javascript:myfunction(1,1,\'just a test\')>` so the actual `href` property parsed by the browser will be: `javascript:myfunction(1,1,\'just` and obviously that's broken. Like I said, wrap the href itself and it will work.

Comment: im sorry..i dont understand what you try to suggest me...i changed the code as you said, then the link will be avascript:myfunction(1,1,\'just a test\'), but the JS function still not work...

Answer (score 2):

Use json_encode(): http://php.net/json_encode

**Update:** Here's a usage example:

```
<?php

$number = 1;
$src_req = 2;
$z = 3;
$src = 4;

$test = 'just a test
with spaces and new lines';
echo "<a href=javascript:myfunction($number,$src_req," . json_encode($test) .")><img style='z-index:$z; src='images/$src'/></a>";
```

If it *doesn't work*, try to find out in what exact way it's not working. A "Does not work" question is as useful as a "Then fix it" answer.

In any case, mixing PHP, HTML, JavaScript and CSS in one single line of code is not worth the effort even for quick testing. Separarte stuff in functions and files you'll make your life easier.

Comment: i did tried to use after $test line in php: json_encode($test); but not worked

Comment: fixed my code as you suggest, but now the link is same as earlier: javascript:myfunction(1,1,"just
the page utf-8 coded.

Comment: @Álv it won't work because there's no wrapping of the `href` so anything after the first space will be parsed as different attribute of the `<a>` element.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - You are right. I've tried to fix the invalid HTML but I just gave up. It's plain crazy to code everything in one line.

Comment: @Álv being classic ASP programmer for long years I'm used to it but I can totally understand what you mean! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the string with php function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) and can use javascripts [unescape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) to unescape.

*you have to parse the third parameter in your js function with unescape ...*

as well you can use json as Álvaro G. Vicario mentioned.

Comment: this almost done, but now in the JS variable the "just a test" shown as "just+a+test"

Comment: hm ... maybe use rawurlencode in php or simply parse the `+` character with: `unescape(param).replace(/\+/,"");`